# JavaScript for loop confusion

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

I'm writing what I think is a straightforward for loop but it is not behaving the way I want it to. I want to understand why it's doing what it's doing:

```js
function pair(str) {

  var finalArray = [];
  var pushArray  = [];
  
  var lookup = {
    G: "C",
    C: "G",
    A: "T",
    T: "A"
  };
  
  for (i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
    pushArray[0] = str[i];
    pushArray[1] = lookup[str[i]];
    finalArray.push(pushArray);
  }
  return finalArray;
}

pair("ATCGG");
```

I want it to return [["A","T"],["T","A"],["C","G"],["G","C"],["G","C"]]

What I'm actually getting is [["G","C"],["G","C"],["G","C"],["G","C"],["G","C"]]

It seems all the ["G","C"] is for where i = 4. Why is my code not looping? What am I missing?

Comment: There's only one `pushArray`, and you're re-using it in each iteration through the loop. You have to make a *new* array on each iteration for it to work the way you expect.

Comment: I thought I was redefining pushArray[0] and pushArray[1] every time the for loop runs? Does JS not let you do that within a for loop?

Comment: Add `pushArray = [];` as the first statement *inside* the loop. That will make a brand new array. You're just pushing the same array on the list over and over again.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh... Thank you so much!!

Comment: **Warning:** Your use of the undeclared variable `i` in your `for` loop is a major bug waiting to happen.  Run your code in strict mode and this will be an error (so you won't accidentally code this way).  Always declare any local variables.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Will keep that in mind. I can see that it'll be a huge issue when writing large complex code.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `finalArray.push(pushArray)` doesn't make a copy of `pushArray`. Each time you do this, you're pushing a reference to the same array, which you then modify on the next iteration. You need to create a new array each time.

```js
function pair(str) {

  var finalArray = [];
  var pushArray;
  
  var lookup = {
    G: "C",
    C: "G",
    A: "T",
    T: "A"
  };
  
  for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
    pushArray = [];
    pushArray[0] = str[i];
    pushArray[1] = lookup[str[i]];
    finalArray.push(pushArray);
  }
  return finalArray;
}
```

Comment: The only answer that explains the problem in the OP.

Comment: So any alteration you made to `pushArray` within that function would modify all of the values contained by `finalArray`?

Comment: Correct, because they're all the same array.

Answer (score 3):

This should help you :)

```js
function pair(str) {      
  var lookup = {
    G: 'C',
    C: 'G',
    A: 'T',
    T: 'A'
  };
  return str.split('').reduce(function(ys,x) {
    return ys.concat([[x, lookup[x]]]);
  }, []);
}

var result = pair('ATCGG');
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
// [["A","T"],["T","A"],["C","G"],["G","C"],["G","C"]]
```

Comment: Thank you! I have so much more I need to learn.... Thought this was going to be an easy problem :/

Answer (score 0):

Your assumptions are partially right , except that everytime you were pushing a reference to same variable.

This should work :

```
function pair(str) {

  var finalArray = [];


  var lookup = {
    G: "C",
    C: "G",
    A: "T",
    T: "A"
  };

  for (i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
  var pushArray=[];
    pushArray[0] = str[i];
    pushArray[1] = lookup[str[i]];
    finalArray.push(pushArray);
  }
  console.log(finalArray.toString())
  return finalArray;
}

pair("ATCGG");
```

**[Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/prollygeek/oz0L3pwz/)**

Comment: It's *not* a scope problem, it's just that the OP's code keeps pushing references to the same array. There are no global variables in the OP's code. Moving the `var` into the for loop makes no difference because variables created with `var` have function scope, not block scope. The only thing that matters is moving the `= []` part, so that a new array is created in each iteration.

Comment: @nnnnnn yes you are right , removed the scope part.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the pushArray is a single instance object and it is over written with new values every time in the for loop.
You can create separated object instance for each str-lookup pair to modify your code as below.

```js
function pair(str) {

  var finalArray = [];
  
  var lookup = {
    G: "C",
    C: "G",
    A: "T",
    T: "A"
  };
  
  for (i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
    finalArray.push([ str[i], lookup[str[i]] ]);
  }
  return finalArray;
}

var res = pair("ATCGG");
alert(JSON.stringify(res));
```

hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace this:

```
finalArray.push(pushArray);
```

With this:

```
finalArray = finalArray.concat(pushArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this - noticing the original post was to determine the base pair sequence in DNA code. I offer the following. The key with the bases array (lookup in the OP) is knowing that each genetic base can only partner with a predetermined other base to give the following combinations (G-C, C-G, A-T, T-A). Therefore the bases array can be simplified, and then it is simple matter of iterating through the passed string, finding the first index of that particular base in the bases array and matching it to the next one (to make a base-pair). Then just pushing the pair into the DNA sequence array. Note that I am "console.logging" it - to demonstrate that this works - rather than using "return".

Knowledge of genetics can be useful even in programming :)

```
pair("ATCGG");

function pair(str) {
  var DNAsequence = [];
  var bases = ["G","C","G","A","T","A"];

  for (i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
      var firstBase=bases.indexOf(str[i]);
      var secondBase=firstBase+1;
      var basePair=[bases[firstBase],bases[secondBase]];

    DNAsequence.push(basePair);
  }
  console.log( DNAsequence);
}
```

and the console.log show the following, as requested:

```
[["A","T"], ["T","A"], ["C","G"], ["G","C"], ["G","C"]]
```